# Saving a generated word to an array/list of words when a button is pressed

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, sorting

I bet this is a pretty simple question for most of you so I'll be quick. Essentially my Swift app generates a random word, and I want the users to be able to select buttons labeled `1` `2` and `3`, and that word is then saved to that particular number in an array. Later on (including after when the app has been closed etc.) the user can view all the words they have assigned a number to. I know it involves creating a new class and placing the respective arrays there but I really have no idea where to start, so any help is appreciated. Sorry if this isn't as clear as you'd like, as you can tell I'm pretty new to Swift/programming. As of right now, all I have related to this part of the app is the buttons:

```
var chosenNumber : String = ""


@IBAction func chosenOne(_ sender: Any) {
    chosenDifficulty = "one"
}
@IBAction func chosenTwo(_ sender: Any) {
    chosenNumber = "two"
}
@IBAction func chosenThree(_ sender: Any) {
    chosenNumber = "three"
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a computedProperty In your ViewController that saves if there's a new value and return the saved value when you access it anywhere in your viewController:

```
 var savedWords: [String: Any]? {
    set{
        guard let value = newValue else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "SavedWords")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            return
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "SavedWords")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    get{
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "SavedWords") as? [String: Any]
    }
}
```

and a dictionary that contains a key-value pair of current words that you're going to add/delete into

```
var currentWords: [String: Any]? = ["button1": "one","button2": "two","button3": "three"]
```

Now, whenever your button is clicked you can add your particular word to **currentWords** dictionary in association with the currentButton key by:

```
currentWords["button1"] = /*selectedValue from button*/
```

After assigning if you want to save those **currentWords** just do

```
self.savedWords = currentWords
```

If you want to retrieve savedWords and assign it to currentWords, you can simply do:

```
self.currentWords = savedWords
```

Comment: I think an Array is not the ideal solution for his problem. The random word has to be assigned to the button which was selected, as far as I understand. Ideally a NSDictionary object should be used to save those random words.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. BCI, how would I go about implementing NSDictionary into this sort of problem. Thanks to both of you

Comment: @mBlot2 I edited my answer, it was previously an array. No, it is using the dictionary as BCI suggested

Comment: When you say to add the line of code that is as follows:

    `currentWords["button1": /*selectedValue from button*/]`

do I add that to the IBAction of button 1 for example? I tried doing that but it says "Expected expression in list of expressions" when I try replacing `/*selectedValue from button*/` with a randomly generated word that is generated when the user presses another button ie:

    `currentWords["chosenEasy" : "(\randomWord)" ]`

thanks

Comment: @mBlot2 Edited!! Please check